# Store iterations in data frame

Tags: r

I want to compute: `val = s*m^y` and store the results for every y iteration in a data frame.

Example:

With m=10, s=1 and 2 iterations of y this would result in:

```
df <- data.frame(y=c(0:2), val = c(1,10,100))
```

I have don't know how to create this data frame.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`^` is vectorized.  No need to iterate.

```
Data <- data.frame(y=0:2)
Data$val <- 1*10^Data$y
```

Comment: Thanks! So easy, I am starting to like R more and more.

Answer (score 3):

You construct a `data.frame` by specifying the values of their columns. To do so, you can use the same vector calculations that you can normally use:

```
> y <- 0:2
> y
[1] 0 1 2
> s <- 1
> m <- 10
> val <- s*m^y
> val
[1] 1 10 100
> df <- data.frame(y=y, val=val)
> df 
  y val
1 0   1
2 1  10
3 2 100
```